# How to hide a CQ component dynamically using Extjs?

Tags: extjs, aem

I need to hide a CQ component from the page, when I select a particular value from another components dialog.  Is this possible using ExtJS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but without more info it is difficult to give more details.  In general, you can look up the xtypes you are using in your dialog at http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html.  Find the events that are available for the xtypes you are using in the dialog, then add a listener for one of the events exposed by that xtype.  That allows you to run your own JavaScript code in response to an event--and that code could do things like hide HTML DOM elements.

Here is an example of using a listener to add custom functionality in response to an event: http://cq.shishank.info/2011/12/20/adding-limit-to-multifiled/

And here is another example: [CQ5 - Hiding a tab within a component dialog depending on user group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165800/cq5-hiding-a-tab-within-a-component-dialog-depending-on-user-group)